# Metric and the Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, metric-tensor

Does the Lagrangian formalism require a metric on the configuration manifold $Q$ in order to define a Lagrangian $L$ on the tangent bundle $TQ$?

Further, if we specify a metric on the tangent bundle then we can via an isomorphism, move this to the cotangent bundle $T^*Q$. That being said how does this metric structure interplay with the symplectic structure?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: [The Lagrangian as a metric](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105726/50583) and [The metric in the Lagrangian](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173028/50583). tl;dr: The Lagrangian does not *require* a metric, but *induces* one from its kinetic term, and conversely, a given metric induces a kinetic term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. On one hand, let there be given a configuration space $(Q,g)$ endowed with a metric $g$. (As ACuriousMind points out in a comment, there is a 1-1 correspondence between a metric $g$ and the kinetic term in a Lagrangian.)
   On the other hand, note that the canonical symplectic 2-form $\omega$ on the cotangent bundle $T^{\ast}Q$ does not depend on the metric $g$ at all, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88925/2451) Phys.SE post. The lesson is to expect no relation between $g$ and $\omega$ generically.
2. Of course, [Kähler manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold) (which assume a compatibility condition between a symplectic and metric structure) are used in many areas of modern theoretical physics. But that is another story.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you are most likely to get one from the kinetic term of the Lagrangian itself. In most cases one requires it to be a convex function in the $\dot q$ variables. You then get a metric if such kinetic term is quadratic in $\dot q$ (and of course sensible kinetic energy is positive-definite).

The metric and symplectic structures on a manifold are usually independent and define to preferential ways of realising isomorphisms between tangent and cotangent bundles (since there is no natural choice in the functorial sense).