# If systems minimize their potential energy, why do people climb mountains?

Tags: potential, potential-energy

A person climbs a mountain. They convert the stored chemical energy of food in their body and back pack into heat energy on the mountain, and gravitational potential energy as they move towards the top.

Why?

From a physics perspective, shouldn't this mean that some form of potential energy is lowered when people accomplish goals?

*Edit*: Commenters have given the example of air molecules as running counter to my premise.   This is a good answer that helps to get at the core of the question.

The question isn't "why do people not always seek the minimum potential energy" - but rather, why do they sometimes move *against* the energy gradient, when all other physical systems move with it?

The comment says "the prediction of the principle is that the atmosphere should all fall down to the ground. "     This is a misreading of the principle i'm talking about.

In reality, air molecules fall until their pressure increases - and gas under pressure has energy, too.  If molecules fell further, the *total* energy would go up.

In other words, air molecules fall until total energy is minimized. If they fell any further, the decrease in gravitational potential would be offset by the increase in the pressure of the atmosphere times its volume.

Comment: Isolated systems will tend towards lower potential energy states. However, we are not isolated systems and nothing says that increasing the potential energy of a system is forbidden

Comment: "Systems minimize their potential energy" is a very simplistic statement. Why, then, does a undamped oscillator oscillate (thereby constantly changing potential and kinetic energy) and not simply come to rest? What about statistical systems out of equilibrium?

Comment: if you're going to downvote, please explain yourself at least.  

[this question here is relevant](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113092/why-does-a-system-try-to-minimize-potential-energy).

Comment: If you really believe in physics, there should be a way to explain this through physics. I believe in physics, which is why i've asked the question here. 

Humans are physical objects. So we should be obeying the same physical laws as everyone else, right?

Comment: You're right. But there is no law that says every action must lower the potential energy. If there's no reason to believe it shouldn't happen, there's not much reason to explain why it does

Comment: I downvoted because your question isn't about physics but the capability and desire of a human to do something.

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v1): Replace the word _why_ with _how._

Comment: [Because they're in love?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU2ftCitvyQ)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about human behaviour, not physics.

Answer (score 2):

So the principle that systems find themselves at an energy minimum needs to be heavily qualified: it is a consequence of ever-present friction/drag forces having a sign opposite to your velocity, so that the [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)) wasted due to friction is terminally negative.

The principle therefore states, "when a system only has two forces, one due to drag and the other due to a potential energy, the system tends to end up at a minimum of the potential energy."

There are many situations where it does not readily apply. One of the most obvious is air molecules in our atmosphere! The prediction of the principle is that the atmosphere should all fall down to the ground: obviously that's not happening! The basic reason why involves a more detailed understanding of *thermodynamics*: the *friction* in this case transfers energy to the molecule's *surroundings*, which is either the ground or other air molecules. In turn, "kicks" from the thermal motion of the ground and other air molecules keep those air molecules suspended in midair.

Another situation where it doesn't apply is a rocket blasting off. Here, there is another force: the force of the hot gases that the rocket is expelling out its rear end. As long as those forces continue, that rocket's not going to find its way to the ground. If those forces stop, then the rocket may nevertheless have enough kinetic energy to leave the solar system. (One could fix the principle by saying that it either ends up at a potential energy minimum or else "at infinity", perhaps.)

Another situation where it doesn't apply is static friction. There are lots of things on my desk that, if humanity disappeared tomorrow, would I suppose eventually get jostled to the floor as plants and animals reclaim Kansas City. But my desk stays together because of static friction of screws, and the stuff on my desk stays on my desk due to its static friction with that surface. Static friction holds things together in such a way that there is no motion, hence there is no drag force, hence the power is not being dissipated.

As you have noticed, there is a "combination" of these other systems, burning food chemically to engage muscles so that a biological system can use static friction to ascend a mountain, where we end up violating the principle. That's OK, because it was just a useful little rule of thumb in the first place. It doesn't have the status of a fundamental Theory of Physics or anything.

There is a principle which is a little like it, known as the Second Law of Thermodynamics, which does indeed apply here too. One way to phrase it is, "to transfer the energy in a degree of freedom further away from the average, other degrees of freedom always need to go closer to the average commensurately." Our uncertainty about where energy is in the various degrees of freedom of a system can be quantified as a number called **entropy**. The way that you increase your gravitational-potential-energy degree of freedom when you climb up a mountain is by taking stockpiles of chemical energy in the form of food and stored fat, burning them up (lowering their energy to be much closer to the environment's) with a biochemical process which causes your muscles to store and expel energy, and you use your intelligence and a concerted motion of these muscles to push yourself up the mountain (using those muscles' energy to raise the gravitational energy of your center of mass). Indeed, you cannot do it if you are severely malnourished.

Comment: This is a really good answer to a really weird question.

Comment: This is a good answer that helps to get at the core of the question.

The question isn't "why do people not always seek the minimum potential energy" - but rather, why do they sometimes move _against_ the energy gradient, when all other physical systems move with it?   Look at your examples:  you say, "the prediction of the principle is that the atmosphere should all fall down to the ground. "   In reality, air molecules fall until their pressure increases - and gas under pressure has energy, too.  If molecules fell further, the *total* energy would go up. They fall until energy is minimized.