# Drops and surface tension

Tags: surface-tension

When a drop of liquid splits into a number of drops, each drop tries to minimize its area but the overall surface area of drops increases. How does the overall surface area of the drops increase????

Comment: I just tried to mathematically split a drop of volume "V" into two drops of volume "V/2".  When I did, the total surface area remained constant.  Do you have an example to go along with your question?

Comment: Try the derivation of the work done in splitting a bigger drop into n smaller drops in this topic it is given in the introductory paragraph that when a drop of radius R splits into smaller n  dropswhere is drop tries to minimise its area but the overall surface area of the drop increases I want to know why does the surface area of the drops increase when each drop tries to minimise its area

Comment: As Monocerotis pointed out, the total area remains the same, but the surface-area/volume ratio increases.

Comment: @DavidWhite *the total surface area remained constant* Can you doublecheck? I found that the surface area increases as the cube root of the number of droplets.

Comment: @G.Smith, I just checked the case of splitting one drop into two while holding the total volume constant.  For an initial volume of $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ with an area of $4 \pi r^2$, a drop half that volume has a volume of $\frac{2}{3} \pi r^3$.  I took the derivative of that to arrive at an area of $2 \pi r^2$ for the half sized drop.  Was that an error on my part?

Comment: @G.Smith, never mind ... my assumed "quick" method proved to be incorrect.  You are right.  The area increases as the number of drops increase.

Comment: @DavidWhite Agreed, but I can’t put my finger on why your derivative method is invalid.

Comment: @G.Smith, something apparently went wrong with the $r^3$ or $r^2$ term.  I'll have to think about this issue for a bit to find out where it went wrong.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the overall surface area of the drops increase????

It’s just geometry.

The area of a sphere with radius $r$ is $A=4\pi r^2$ and the volume is $V=\frac43\pi r^3$, so the relationship between area and volume for one sphere is

$$A_1=4\pi\left(\frac{3V_1}{4\pi}\right)^{2/3}=CV_1^{2/3}$$

where $C$ is a numerical constant.

Now suppose one sphere of volume $V_1$ divides into $N$ spheres each of volume $V_1/N$. Their total area will be

$$A_N=NC\left(\frac{V_1}{N}\right)^{2/3}$$

or

$$A_N=N^{1/3}A_1.$$

Thus the area increases as the cube root of the number of spheres.

Answer (score 1):

It does not try to minimize it's total surface area,rather it minimizes it's $\frac{surface \\\ area}{volume} $ ratio to attain minimum potential and thus the droplets assume spherical shapes as it is the best way to do so.

Comment: What is the benefit of attaining a minimum potential

Comment: @HenaAnvar That's a different question altogether and is not meant to be answered in the comments section. Possible answer to your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113092/why-does-a-system-try-to-minimize-potential-energy

Comment: that begs for a completely new question,but in gist minimum energy means lower internal energy of the constituent particles which means more stability