# Explanation and quantum gravity

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion

Is spacetime accelerating? Is it accelerating within an acceleration ?Or is it a constant?

(are different objects or particles influenced by other rates in spacetime compared to one-another and if so how are things evolving for perception of time and space?)

Most question raising finding previous me asking this question :

The 3D vector showing perceptions of time ,space and location changing for different positions even so events appear to have a follow up of events in the 3D vector even the order of events can be different to the other position

Comment: This does not make sense. Even accounting for spelling errors, what does "grow on the outside" or "everything on it expanding" mean?

Comment: There is no "outside to the universe". The universe is not a thing that lives in some other, bigger thing. It is the biggest thing there is and that means there is nothing bigger. What we mean by "the universe grows" is that there is more space inside as time goes by. You can go more places, even though those places are ever more empty because the mass inside the universe does not seem to grow. The things in here all stay the same, they are just ever farther apart from each other. If we could live a billion years, we would easily notice that things are moving apart.

Comment: Curiuos Thats my question ...when everything is expending ..is iT possible that planets expend ass Well but at a diffent rate ? And everything on iT expends so there is no change in laws of nature and messurements ....

Comment: Sorry Im no professor ...I really do not know..

Comment: The planets and the solar system and the galaxies are not expanding, at least not at a measurable rate, at this point. One can construct theoretical models in which the universe will end in a giant "big rip" event, which will rip everything apart, even the planets and the stars and eventually the atoms and nuclei, but that's a model, not confirmed physics. What is going to happen, if the current expansion continues at the measured rate, is that the sky is going to go dark with exception of our own galaxy. It will be a dark universe in which one won't be able to observe the past any longer.

Comment: Related question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7359/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a model that might get you many features you look for. Imagine a balloon.

Imagine the surface is expanding. If it is like bubble gum then as it expands it gets thinner and expands more easily, and it could pop. If however you had some objects free to move around the surface but attached by springs then they might slow the expansion and even make the whole balloon slow its expansion, eventually stopping, and then contracting until it all crashes together (don't imagine the balloon as having air in it, just parts that were all rushing away from each other). Maybe it was made out of rockets that all shot away from a common center with a big explosion and then we just cruising outwards with some velocity.

OK. Not what if time was the radial distance from the center. Then at every moment you have a different sized 2d space and whether it will expand forever is really a function of how strong those springs are compared to how much it was expanding outwards.

That model isn't entirely accurate. Among other others things you'd need a 3d surface in  4d spacetime. But you see some features. Firstly, each point looks the same as all the other points at the same time. Each sees a universe that is expanding. And it is expanding into the future, not into some larger space. The current universe always becomes the future universe and there is room in the future for the universe to be larger and every point can look the same.

When you have too few springs things fly apart forever and when there are too many it eventually slows how fast it expands. And there is some magic critical amount right between the two.

Out universe has regular matter attract things to it, much like the springs. The universe is expanding but the matter acts to slow that down. But we see things expand in a way as if we are really close to that cut off. And we don't see enough matter to explain that.

So we think there must be more matter we can't see that makes it be like that. And it's nice to be like that, the universe can get large enough to have interesting things in it but not have everything so far away they can't see each other.  If you lived in the balloon and tried to send something around the balloon to your friend that also lived in the balloon then the thing you send would have to go to the future (everything is going to the future). So you could mark the point halfway between your friend and you and so if the balloon got so large by the time that your message got to the original halfway point that the halfway was now farther than you friend originally was and it keeps expanding fast enough to make that happen then your message is never to reach your friend.

So expanding universes have regions that can never communicate. And we have some evidence that our universe might have something like an antispring that makes regions without springs (mass, regular energy, momentum, stress, and pressure all act gravitationally like springs) expand faster and faster. And since it makes more empty space and the empty space has that property, it is a long term win for the dark energy.

We don't really know much about dark energy or dark matter, the dark matter acts normal but we've only ever seen it gravitationally and don't know what it would be made out of. Dark energy is even less well understood.

Now an important thing to note is that in regions with more springs than average the space could not expand even if in a large scale it does still expand, and the things that set the sizes of things ate the interactions between the parts. So any effect of expansion has already affected the size of things. Just as any size of contraction. For instance the earth is smaller than it otherwise would be because it is attracting itself together we don't need to throw that in one top of other effects.

So you are already seeing the things be as close as they are because of all the effects.

In the regions between the galaxies the density is lower than the critical density so they will get bigger and dark energy could make them get even bigger in a run away fashion. Regions with a critical density will not be getting bigger in a run away fashion and if they are greater than critical density they could slow the expansion in that region.

Comment: That sure answers the biggest part of the question ! Thank you ! And I will look into it more ...

Comment: @KristelRemie I don't understand what you're saying. Anything is possible, the real question is whether it agrees with the regular patterns and observations we've made. And even if things are expanding now they could slow and even contract or could expand faster and faster and it's up to us to find the the pattern that fits it all. We noticed that things in the solar system behave differently depending on how much mass and energy and such is there, but then things seem to move differently at big scales so there should be matter we don't see, dark matter for instance. It's a process of learning

Comment: I believe iT does not contradict with existing information (at least not that I can think of ,but I could be wrong ...)  thanks for making time explaning 

Comment: THE balloon ...in your explanation ..