# How is the Universe expanding faster than the speed of light?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, faster-than-light

I was watching a youtube video about the expansion of the universe. So the video said that the universe is expanding at a speed faster than the speed of light. I have 2 questions about that. My first question is doesn't this contradict einstein's theory of relativity that states nothing can travel faster than the speed of light.  please note that i did look at some other questions similar to this one but i couldnt find an answer to my question. My second question is where does the universe expand to. If the unviverse holds all matter then where does it expand to. If it expands to nothing there would be nothing to expand to right. Is the universe creating space?
ps, please keep in mind i am only 13 so it would be great if you could keep your answers as simple as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can space expand with unlimited speed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/)

Comment: Hi Don. This is a popular question and has already been asked several times. The question I've linked has several answers ranging from simplified to highly mathematical, so you should find something suitable amongst them.

Comment: Re your second question, have a look at [If the universe is expanding, what is it expanding into?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/if-the-universe-is-expanding-what-is-it-expanding-into) and [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point)